# Can the search window include other sites such as superuser.com?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While I get the need for separation of SE sites, I found myself in a situation where the answer I was looking for wasn't on ServerFault but rather SuperUser.  Typically I don't venture over there very often, but something in me thought "I wonder if they know?"  I've also found this to be true on NetworkEngineering.stackexchange.com but since that's in beta I'll leave that one be.  In theory I guess I could use Google and set site: info there to query both of them, but a little too much work to be honest.

So, I'm interested in this discussion and possibly feature-request.

**Can the search window query additional results on sites other than ServerFault.com?**

Positive reasons to do so:

- New folks that quickly search for "How do I uninstall a program on Windows 8?" here and don't get an easy result won't just fire off a new question.  The additional results from Superuser.com would help quell this.
- Helps the point of a "network of sites" instead of disparate sites on their own island
- More collaboration/information is usually a good thing

Negative reasons to do so:

- SU might want the same on their site...which could lead non sysadmins here
- The sites user database isn't the same, requiring them to create an account on the sister site if they want to upvote a question/answer they find in search (I don't care about this, but some might)

Comment: Nobody who needs to do so ever uses search.

Comment: @Iain - I get your jaded point, trust me I do, but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: It's not jaded, it's reality.

Comment: I agree it's reality...Jaded (a) = "tired, bored, or lacking enthusiasm, **typically after having had too much of something**"

Comment: I don't see how reality can be jaded ... to EL.se ... cba ... QED

Comment: I still think experts like myself will use the functionality, even if the devops and riff raff from SO won't.

Comment: SE search is though less than useful even when you know what you're looking for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232242/help-us-find-duplicates-efficiently

Comment: Concur @Iain especially on the dupe/canonical search issue-- I can stick with google...heck I can stick with google without the site: parameter and not care if it's in the SE stack or not.  Just thought it'd be a nice to have...but if the entire search functionality sucks then I'll digress.  I'd rather that be fixed first.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen the [network-wide search](http://stackexchange.com/search) at [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that.  But it's just a glorified Google search page which was where I was going with the "I could use Google" part.  It'd be nice to have the normal search functionality (user:me , [tag] etc.).

Comment: At the moment, Google search appears to be superior to SE's internal search engine...

Comment: At the moment, printing questions on paper, sticking them to a wall printed side down and throwing darts at them while hoping really hard you hit something useful would probably give the SE internal search engine a run for its money.